# Approximating a number by using only a given set of prime-factors for the approximant.

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization, diophantine-approximation

Let $n  \in\mathbb{N},$ and $S$ be a (finite) set of prime numbers.
I'm looking for an efficient algorithm to find the greatest $m\leq n$ such that $m$'s prime factors are of $S$?

For $S=\{p\}$ the answer is  $\;m = p^{\lfloor\log_{p}(n)\rfloor}\;$ where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the floor of $x$.

For  $S=\{p, q\}$ the aim would be to aproximate $\ln(n)$ as: $$\;a\ln(p) + b\ln(q)$$ where $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers (ie. $p^aq^b = n$).  However, I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I suggest you spell out the question in the question body, and not just squeeze the main content into the title.

Comment: The search space is finite so of course there is such an algorithm: you start with $n$, find prime factors, and subtract $1$ if you find a prime factor not in $S$. It's not a very *efficient* algorithm...

Comment: A brute force algorithm that might be more practical is to try all possible values for one of the exponents and recurse on each resulting subproblem.

Comment: The OP's final reformulation shows that this is a special case of the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem): we're trying to squeeze in as many copies of $\log p$, $\log q$, ... as we can into a "knapsack" of size $\log n$. That should help search for efficient algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

If S is not too large, say 10 elements, then you can systematically enumerate all integers made of factors in S.

If S is so large that a substantial fraction of integers are made of factors in S, then you should be able to create a sieve containing all numbers with factors not in S.